# python os.read(fd, n) requires parameter n, why?

Tags: python

I need to read a text file with the os module as such:

```
t = os.open('te.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
r = os.read(t, 20)
rs = r.decode('utf-8')
print(rs)
```

What if I don't know the byte size of the file. I could put a very large number instead of 20 as a value seems to be required, but perhaps there is a more pythonic way.

Comment: *I need to read* -- Why?  The `os` file functions offer little value over the normal `file` objects.

Comment: Run `man 2 read` to see the documentation for the underlying syscall. That call requires a maximum length, so its wrapper does too.

Comment: (_Why_ it requires a maximum length goes down to implementation details: There's no such thing as dynamic allocation of userspace memory from inside the OS kernel; even though the kernel allocates address space to applications, `malloc()` and the like is used in the C library to manage that memory more granularly, as opposed to "this is the start and the end of the range of memory you can access")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to load the whole file and you have to use `os`, you could use `os.stat(filename).st_size` or `os.path.getsize(filename)` to get the size of the file in bytes.

```
filename = 'te.txt'
t = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
b = os.stat(filename).st_size
r = os.read(t, b)
rs = r.decode('utf-8')
print(rs)
```

Comment: Even this won't necessarily work because `read` isn't guaranteed to satisfy the whole request at once. You need a loop around it.

Comment: Thanks to C. Duffy illuminating comments and I was able to use the above successfully.

Comment: @rearThing, ... This is only expected to be successful with fairly small files; depending on your OS, filesystem, and the host's load profile the place where short reads become likely may be as little as 4kb. I don't know why you would prefer it over something that doesn't bother with the `stat`, and adds a loop to read remaining content if the OS didn't give you the entire content of the file in the first request.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument *isn't supposed to hold* the size of the file in bytes; it's only supposed to hold the maximum amount of content you're prepared to read at a time (which should typically be divisible by both your operating system's block size and page size; 64kb is not a bad default).

The "why" of this is because memory has to be allocated in userspace before the kernel can be instructed to write content into that memory. This isn't the kind of detail that Python developers need to think about often, but you're using a low-level interface built for use from C; it accordingly has implementation details [leaking out of](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) that underlying layer.

The operating system is free to give you less than the number of bytes you indicate as a maximum (for example, if it gets interrupted, or the filesystem driver isn't written to provide that much data at a time), so no matter what, you need to be prepared to call it repeatedly; only when it returns an empty string (as opposed to throwing an exception or returning a shorter-than-requested string) are you certain to have reached the end of the file.

`os.read()` **isn't a Pythonic interface, and it isn't supposed to be.** It's a thin wrapper around the syscall provided by the operating system kernel. If you want a Pythonic interface, don't use `os.read()`, but instead use Python's native file objects.

Comment: *"when it returns an empty string have you reached the end of the file"* - Is that documented somewhere? I can only see the converse: when end of file is reached, then empty string is returned.

Comment: @Pychopath, the only documentation I can point you for that is not for the Python wrapper but the underlying C function and the syscall that C function wraps; see `man 2 read`. I was a C developer before I was a Python developer; this aspect of `read()`'s behavior is well-known and widely relied on in the C world.

Comment: @Pychopath, ...to quote: *If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.* -- so EOF is the only zero-byte-read case where you _don't_ have an error given to Python to transform into an exception.